# Shader Editor does not reflect on action

Tags: shaders

I was trying to adjust the nodes for object and world, but the shader editor is not responding as shown in the gif. May i know what caused this problem and how could i fix it?

[image]

**Thank You so much for helping.**

Comment: This is not how background textures work. You need to have an **HDRi image** (hdrihaven.com) and you need to hook it up to the output through a **background image node, not a Principled BSDF**. The easiest way to do this is by just opening it on the right side in your world properties, where it says "open". You might want to delete your broken node setup first.

Comment: yea thanks for trying to help. I know i should plug an environment texture on the world node setup, but the problem is i cant navigate to there, since it is broken like the gif shows. It is not linking with any of the object i clicked.

Comment: You have "pinned" the object texture shader editor window. Just click on the pin icon on the middle of the screen next to where you change the name of your materials. For your information this is useful when you want to tweak several materials at a time because by default, the shader editor window shows the material of the select object

Comment: Thanks :D I cant believe i wasted 2 hours for this, but i did learned a lesson from it lol. May i know is there any short cut key to enable it? I dont think i did it intentionally.